# Avast attempts to connect to the Internet when I try to download email

Tags: email, antivirus

The file AVAST (Software\Avast\AvastSvc.exe) tries to connect when I check my email. When I forbid access to the internet for AvastSvc.exe, I can't connect to POP3 & SMTP.

I'm not sure where all of my emails are going when AvastSvc.exe have access to the internet. I think it's a tricky security issue.

Comment: It's not a tricky security issue, it's what you have agreed to by using Avast's services.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you have Avast Mail Shield active and therefore it will scan any incoming and outgoing messages. This is probably done by being a man in the middle, i.e. your mail client actually connects to a local process from Avast which then connects to the real mail server.

This means the internet access is necessary to actually get the mails from the internet, analyze them and then forward them to your mail client. There is no need to send these mails to Avast for analysis same as there is no need to send your local files to Avast for analysis. But it is necessary for the Avast process to actually reach the internet because otherwise it could not get your mails for analysis.

Apart from that you should ask yourself if your distrust makes any sense: you trust Avast to inspect all your locally stored data, you trust Avast to connect to the internet to get updates but you don't trust Avast to connect to the internet when you get mail? If Avast would like to transfer your mails it could be easily done during the software/pattern update.

Comment: That's not the point, the point is - where all of these e-mails are transferred, what for, Are they stored, for what purpose ? That's what I'm talking about. ;)

Comment: @Tomas: again. "This is probably done by being a man in the middle,....". This means the internet access is necessary to actually get the mails from the internet, analyze them and then forward them to your mail client. There is no need to send these mails to Avast for analysis same as there is no need to send your local files to Avast for analysis. But it is necessary for the Avast process to actually reach the internet because otherwise it could not get your mails for analysis.

Comment: @Tomas if that's your real question, then you need to contact Avast support for those technical details. We can' possibly know Avast's internal architecture.

Comment: @schroeder I added your comment to the answer, as I felt it added significant value. Not sure what the etiquette around editing answers is; please let me know if I broke it.

Comment: @Anders: you've actually added mine and not schroeder's comment to my answer and I think it was a good idea.